# "Group by" in Google Sheets - finding distinct values for each column?

Tags: google-sheets, group-by, pivot-table, formula

I have a table in Google Sheets with 4 descriptive columns and 1 numerical column (Ex. State, Region, Ethnic Group, Education Level, Population).

**I'd like to create a new table in a separate tab with the distinct values for some descriptive fields and the median of the numerical field - what is the best way to do this dynamically?**

If it helps, I know this is what it would look like in SQL (below), I just don't know how to do it in sheets ;)

```
select state, region, ethnic_group, median(population) as med_population
    from TABLE
    group by state, region, ethnic_group
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(A:D; 
 "select A,B,C,avg(D) 
  where A is not null 
  group by A,B,C 
  label avg(D)'median'"; 1)
```

[image: Sample of usage]